# JMESPath JSON filter with mutiple sub childs

Tags: json, migration, drupal-8, jmespath

I have json block which looks like below. I'm using the [Jmespath](http://jmespath.org) PHP library to get the categories from the below JSON input. I'm using the following query(_element[].[name, display-name, self.uri]) to returns the parent categories in the simple JSON array but it doesn't include the child categories which are inside the _element[]._child[].[name,display-name,self.uri]
How can I combine the two queries into one to fetch the records?

Note: There could _child inside the _child as well i.e. depth of the _child could be till 5 inside the _element. I.e. _element[]._child[].*child[].*

```
{
  "self": {
    "type": "navigations.navigations",
    "uri": "/navigations/cf?zoom=element,element:child,element:child:child,element:child:child:child,element:child:child:child:child",
    "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf?zoom=element,element:child,element:child:child,element:child:child:child,element:child:child:child:child"
  },
  "messages": [],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "element",
      "rev": "list",
      "type": "navigations.navigation",
      "uri": "/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y=",
      "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y="
    },
    {
      "rel": "element",
      "rev": "list",
      "type": "navigations.navigation",
      "uri": "/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt=",
      "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt="
    },
    {
      "rel": "element",
      "rev": "list",
      "type": "navigations.navigation",
      "uri": "/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom=",
      "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom="
    },
    {
      "rel": "element",
      "rev": "list",
      "type": "navigations.navigation",
      "uri": "/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg=",
      "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg="
    }
  ],
  "_element": [
    {
      "self": {
        "type": "navigations.navigation",
        "uri": "/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y=",
        "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y="
      },
      "messages": [],
      "links": [
        {
          "rel": "top",
          "type": "navigations.navigations",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
        },
        {
          "rel": "child",
          "rev": "parent",
          "type": "navigations.navigation",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf/nfxxg=",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/nfxxg="
        },
        {
          "rel": "child",
          "rev": "parent",
          "type": "navigations.navigation",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf/ifxgi4tjn5sa=",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/ifxgi4tjn5sa="
        },
        {
          "rel": "items",
          "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
          "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y=/1",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y=/1"
        }
      ],
      "_child": [
        {
          "self": {
            "type": "navigations.navigation",
            "uri": "/navigations/cf/nfxxg=",
            "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/nfxxg="
          },
          "messages": [],
          "links": [
            {
              "rel": "parent",
              "rev": "child",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y="
            },
            {
              "rel": "top",
              "type": "navigations.navigations",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
            },
            {
              "rel": "items",
              "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
              "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/nfxxg=/1",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/nfxxg=/1"
            }
          ],
          "details": [
            {
              "display-name": "Category Description",
              "display-value": "IOS",
              "name": "catDescription",
              "value": "IOS"
            },
            {
              "display-name": "Name",
              "display-value": "IOS",
              "name": "catName",
              "value": "IOS"
            }
          ],
          "display-name": "IOS",
          "name": "ios"
        },
        {
          "self": {
            "type": "navigations.navigation",
            "uri": "/navigations/cf/ifxgi4tjn5sa=",
            "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/ifxgi4tjn5sa="
          },
          "messages": [],
          "links": [
            {
              "rel": "parent",
              "rev": "child",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y="
            },
            {
              "rel": "top",
              "type": "navigations.navigations",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
            },
            {
              "rel": "items",
              "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
              "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/ifxgi4tjn5sa=/1",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/ifxgi4tjn5sa=/1"
            }
          ],
          "details": [
            {
              "display-name": "Category Description",
              "display-value": "Andriod cellphones",
              "name": "catDescription",
              "value": "Andriod cellphones"
            },
            {
              "display-name": "Name",
              "display-value": "Andriod cellphones",
              "name": "catName",
              "value": "Andriod cellphones"
            }
          ],
          "display-name": "Andriod",
          "name": "Andriod"
        }
      ],
      "details": [
        {
          "display-name": "Category Description",
          "display-value": "Smartphones",
          "name": "catDescription",
          "value": "Smartphones"
        },
        {
          "display-name": "Name",
          "display-value": "Smartphones",
          "name": "catName",
          "value": "Smartphones"
        }
      ],
      "display-name": "Smartphones",
      "name": "cf_smartphones"
    },
    {
      "self": {
        "type": "navigations.navigation",
        "uri": "/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt=",
        "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt="
      },
      "messages": [],
      "links": [
        {
          "rel": "top",
          "type": "navigations.navigations",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
        },
        {
          "rel": "child",
          "rev": "parent",
          "type": "navigations.navigation",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf/irgfeu2mki=",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/irgfeu2mki="
        },
        {
          "rel": "items",
          "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
          "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt=/1",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt=/1"
        }
      ],
      "_child": [
        {
          "self": {
            "type": "navigations.navigation",
            "uri": "/navigations/cf/irgfeu2mki=",
            "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/irgfeu2mki="
          },
          "messages": [],
          "links": [
            {
              "rel": "parent",
              "rev": "child",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt="
            },
            {
              "rel": "top",
              "type": "navigations.navigations",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
            },
            {
              "rel": "items",
              "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
              "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/irgfeu2mki=/1",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/irgfeu2mki=/1"
            }
          ],
          "details": [
            {
              "display-name": "Category Description",
              "display-value": "DLR SLR Cameras",
              "name": "catDescription",
              "value": "DLR SLR Cameras"
            },
            {
              "display-name": "Name",
              "display-value": "DLR SLR Cameras",
              "name": "catName",
              "value": "DLR SLR Cameras"
            }
          ],
          "display-name": "Digital SLR",
          "name": "DLRSLR"
        }
      ],
      "details": [
        {
          "display-name": "Category Description",
          "display-value": "Cameras",
          "name": "catDescription",
          "value": "Cameras"
        },
        {
          "display-name": "Name",
          "display-value": "Cameras",
          "name": "catName",
          "value": "Cameras"
        }
      ],
      "display-name": "Cameras",
      "name": "cf_cameras"
    },
    {
      "self": {
        "type": "navigations.navigation",
        "uri": "/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom=",
        "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom="
      },
      "messages": [],
      "links": [
        {
          "rel": "top",
          "type": "navigations.navigations",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
        },
        {
          "rel": "child",
          "rev": "parent",
          "type": "navigations.navigation",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna=",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna="
        },
        {
          "rel": "items",
          "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
          "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom=/1",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom=/1"
        }
      ],
      "_child": [
        {
          "self": {
            "type": "navigations.navigation",
            "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna=",
            "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna="
          },
          "messages": [],
          "links": [
            {
              "rel": "parent",
              "rev": "child",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom="
            },
            {
              "rel": "top",
              "type": "navigations.navigations",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
            },
            {
              "rel": "child",
              "rev": "parent",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mrqxiylsmvrw65tfoj4q=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mrqxiylsmvrw65tfoj4q="
            },
            {
              "rel": "child",
              "rev": "parent",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/ozuxe5ltm52wc4te=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/ozuxe5ltm52wc4te="
            },
            {
              "rel": "child",
              "rev": "parent",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mrqxiyluojqw443gmvza=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mrqxiyluojqw443gmvza="
            },
            {
              "rel": "items",
              "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
              "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna=/1",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna=/1"
            }
          ],
          "_child": [
            {
              "self": {
                "type": "navigations.navigation",
                "uri": "/navigations/cf/mrqxiylsmvrw65tfoj4q=",
                "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mrqxiylsmvrw65tfoj4q="
              },
              "messages": [],
              "links": [
                {
                  "rel": "parent",
                  "rev": "child",
                  "type": "navigations.navigation",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna=",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna="
                },
                {
                  "rel": "top",
                  "type": "navigations.navigations",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
                },
                {
                  "rel": "items",
                  "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
                  "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/mrqxiylsmvrw65tfoj4q=/1",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/mrqxiylsmvrw65tfoj4q=/1"
                }
              ],
              "details": [
                {
                  "display-name": "Category Description",
                  "display-value": "Data Recovery",
                  "name": "catDescription",
                  "value": "Data Recovery"
                },
                {
                  "display-name": "Name",
                  "display-value": "Data Recovery",
                  "name": "catName",
                  "value": "Data Recovery"
                }
              ],
              "display-name": "Data Recovery",
              "name": "datarecovery"
            },
            {
              "self": {
                "type": "navigations.navigation",
                "uri": "/navigations/cf/ozuxe5ltm52wc4te=",
                "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/ozuxe5ltm52wc4te="
              },
              "messages": [],
              "links": [
                {
                  "rel": "parent",
                  "rev": "child",
                  "type": "navigations.navigation",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna=",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna="
                },
                {
                  "rel": "top",
                  "type": "navigations.navigations",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
                },
                {
                  "rel": "items",
                  "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
                  "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/ozuxe5ltm52wc4te=/1",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/ozuxe5ltm52wc4te=/1"
                }
              ],
              "details": [
                {
                  "display-name": "Category Description",
                  "display-value": "Virus Guard",
                  "name": "catDescription",
                  "value": "Virus Guard"
                },
                {
                  "display-name": "Name",
                  "display-value": "Virus Guard",
                  "name": "catName",
                  "value": "Virus Guard"
                }
              ],
              "display-name": "Virus Guard",
              "name": "virusguard"
            },
            {
              "self": {
                "type": "navigations.navigation",
                "uri": "/navigations/cf/mrqxiyluojqw443gmvza=",
                "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mrqxiyluojqw443gmvza="
              },
              "messages": [],
              "links": [
                {
                  "rel": "parent",
                  "rev": "child",
                  "type": "navigations.navigation",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna=",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna="
                },
                {
                  "rel": "top",
                  "type": "navigations.navigations",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
                },
                {
                  "rel": "items",
                  "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
                  "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/mrqxiyluojqw443gmvza=/1",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/mrqxiyluojqw443gmvza=/1"
                }
              ],
              "details": [
                {
                  "display-name": "Category Description",
                  "display-value": "Data Transfer",
                  "name": "catDescription",
                  "value": "Data Transfer"
                },
                {
                  "display-name": "Name",
                  "display-value": "Data Transfer",
                  "name": "catName",
                  "value": "Data Transfer"
                }
              ],
              "display-name": "Data Transfer",
              "name": "datatransfer"
            }
          ],
          "details": [
            {
              "display-name": "Category Description",
              "display-value": "Professional Tech",
              "name": "catDescription",
              "value": "Professional Tech"
            },
            {
              "display-name": "Name",
              "display-value": "Professional Tech",
              "name": "catName",
              "value": "Professional Tech"
            }
          ],
          "display-name": "Professional Tech",
          "name": "professionaltech"
        }
      ],
      "details": [
        {
          "display-name": "Category Description",
          "display-value": "Services",
          "name": "catDescription",
          "value": "Services"
        },
        {
          "display-name": "Name",
          "display-value": "Services",
          "name": "catName",
          "value": "Services"
        }
      ],
      "display-name": "Services",
      "name": "cs_services"
    },
    {
      "self": {
        "type": "navigations.navigation",
        "uri": "/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg=",
        "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg="
      },
      "messages": [],
      "links": [
        {
          "rel": "top",
          "type": "navigations.navigations",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
        },
        {
          "rel": "child",
          "rev": "parent",
          "type": "navigations.navigation",
          "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt=",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt="
        },
        {
          "rel": "items",
          "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
          "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg=/1",
          "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg=/1"
        }
      ],
      "_child": [
        {
          "self": {
            "type": "navigations.navigation",
            "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt=",
            "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt="
          },
          "messages": [],
          "links": [
            {
              "rel": "parent",
              "rev": "child",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg="
            },
            {
              "rel": "top",
              "type": "navigations.navigations",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
            },
            {
              "rel": "child",
              "rev": "parent",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs4dmovzws3ttorqwy3dboruw63q=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs4dmovzws3ttorqwy3dboruw63q="
            },
            {
              "rel": "child",
              "rev": "parent",
              "type": "navigations.navigation",
              "uri": "/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs=",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs="
            },
            {
              "rel": "items",
              "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
              "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt=/1",
              "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt=/1"
            }
          ],
          "_child": [
            {
              "self": {
                "type": "navigations.navigation",
                "uri": "/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs4dmovzws3ttorqwy3dboruw63q=",
                "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs4dmovzws3ttorqwy3dboruw63q="
              },
              "messages": [],
              "links": [
                {
                  "rel": "parent",
                  "rev": "child",
                  "type": "navigations.navigation",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt=",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt="
                },
                {
                  "rel": "top",
                  "type": "navigations.navigations",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
                },
                {
                  "rel": "items",
                  "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
                  "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs4dmovzws3ttorqwy3dboruw63q=/1",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs4dmovzws3ttorqwy3dboruw63q=/1"
                }
              ],
              "details": [
                {
                  "display-name": "Category Description",
                  "display-value": "Delivery + Installation",
                  "name": "catDescription",
                  "value": "Delivery + Installation"
                },
                {
                  "display-name": "Name",
                  "display-value": "Delivery + Installation",
                  "name": "catName",
                  "value": "Delivery + Installation"
                }
              ],
              "display-name": "Delivery + Installation",
              "name": "deliveryplusinstallation"
            },
            {
              "self": {
                "type": "navigations.navigation",
                "uri": "/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs=",
                "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs="
              },
              "messages": [],
              "links": [
                {
                  "rel": "parent",
                  "rev": "child",
                  "type": "navigations.navigation",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt=",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt="
                },
                {
                  "rel": "top",
                  "type": "navigations.navigations",
                  "uri": "/navigations/cf",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/navigations/cf"
                },
                {
                  "rel": "items",
                  "type": "searches.navigation-search-result",
                  "uri": "/searches/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs=/1",
                  "href": "https://www.example.com/searches/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs=/1"
                }
              ],
              "details": [
                {
                  "display-name": "Category Description",
                  "display-value": "Delivery",
                  "name": "catDescription",
                  "value": "Delivery"
                },
                {
                  "display-name": "Name",
                  "display-value": "Delivery",
                  "name": "catName",
                  "value": "Delivery"
                }
              ],
              "display-name": "Delivery",
              "name": "delivery"
            }
          ],
          "details": [
            {
              "display-name": "Category Description",
              "display-value": "Professional Services",
              "name": "catDescription",
              "value": "Professional Services"
            },
            {
              "display-name": "Name",
              "display-value": "Professional Services",
              "name": "catName",
              "value": "Professional Services"
            }
          ],
          "display-name": "Professional Services",
          "name": "professionalservices"
        }
      ],
      "details": [
        {
          "display-name": "Category Description",
          "display-value": "Applicance Services",
          "name": "catDescription",
          "value": "Applicance Services"
        },
        {
          "display-name": "Name",
          "display-value": "Applicance Services",
          "name": "catName",
          "value": "Applicance Services"
        }
      ],
      "display-name": "Applicance Services",
      "name": "applicanceservices"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it but here is my answer:

`_element[*].[{name: name, display-name: display-name, URI: self.uri},_child[*].{name: name, display-name: display-name, URI: self.uri}[],_child[*]._child[][].{name: name, display-name: display-name, URI: self.uri}][][]`

You will get this result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "cf_smartphones",
    "display-name": "Smartphones",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/mntf643nmfzhi4din5xgk4y="
  },
  {
    "name": "ios",
    "display-name": "IOS",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/nfxxg="
  },
  {
    "name": "Andriod",
    "display-name": "Andriod",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/ifxgi4tjn5sa="
  },
  {
    "name": "cf_cameras",
    "display-name": "Cameras",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/mntf6y3bnvsxeylt="
  },
  {
    "name": "DLRSLR",
    "display-name": "Digital SLR",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/irgfeu2mki="
  },
  {
    "name": "cs_services",
    "display-name": "Services",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/mnzv643foj3gsy3fom="
  },
  {
    "name": "professionaltech",
    "display-name": "Professional Tech",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhizldna="
  },
  {
    "name": "datarecovery",
    "display-name": "Data Recovery",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/mrqxiylsmvrw65tfoj4q="
  },
  {
    "name": "virusguard",
    "display-name": "Virus Guard",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/ozuxe5ltm52wc4te="
  },
  {
    "name": "datatransfer",
    "display-name": "Data Transfer",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/mrqxiyluojqw443gmvza="
  },
  {
    "name": "applicanceservices",
    "display-name": "Applicance Services",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/mfyha3djmnqw4y3fonsxe5tjmnsxg="
  },
  {
    "name": "professionalservices",
    "display-name": "Professional Services",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/obzg6ztfonzws33omfwhgzlsozuwgzlt="
  },
  {
    "name": "deliveryplusinstallation",
    "display-name": "Delivery + Installation",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs4dmovzws3ttorqwy3dboruw63q="
  },
  {
    "name": "delivery",
    "display-name": "Delivery",
    "URI": "/navigations/cf/mrswy2lwmvzhs="
  }
]
```